# Align a label and two DIVs horizontally with CSS

Tags: css

I have this form, that I can't edit:

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post" class="adverts-form adverts-form-aligned">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="adverts-control-group adverts-field-text adverts-field-name-adverts_eventLength ">
            <label for="adverts_eventLength">Durata evenimentului</label>
            <span class="ui-spinner ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
                <input name="adverts_eventLength" id="adverts_eventLength" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="999" autocomplete="off" class="ui-spinner-input" role="spinbutton" type="text">
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="adverts-control-group adverts-field-select adverts-field-name-adverts_eventUnits ">
            <label for="adverts_eventUnits">&nbsp;</label>
                <select id="adverts_eventUnits" name="adverts_eventUnits" style="">
                    <option value="zile">zile</option>
                    <option value="săptămâni">săptămâni</option>
                    <option value="luni">luni</option>
                    <option value="ani">ani</option>
                </select>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

I want to align inline horizontally the two form DIVs, but keeping the position and the width of the first DIV label unchanged. Is there a way to do this with CSS?

This is the working (solved) solution: https://jsfiddle.net/iuriemalai/cp7kvLrw/32/

Answer (score 1):

You can just float it.

```
.adverts-form-aligned .adverts-control-group > label {
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
}
.adverts-form input[type="text"] {
    width: 60%;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it like

```
.adverts-form-aligned .adverts-control-group > label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
.adverts-control-group {
  float: left;
}
.adverts-form input[type="text"] {
    width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for your answer?

Comment: @biogenx I tried to reduce the code size in my question, but this also reduced my chance to receive an answer with a working solution. Anyway, I received from you a very good suggestion. Thank you very much! I updated my question with a more complete code, and also I published my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS code that helped to solve my problem:

```
body .adverts-form.adverts-form-aligned .adverts-field-name-adverts_eventLength {
    overflow: initial;
}

.adverts-form.adverts-form-aligned .adverts-control-group.adverts-field-text.adverts-field-name-adverts_eventLength label,
.adverts-form.adverts-form-aligned .adverts-field-name-adverts_eventLength .ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
    float: left;
}

body .adverts-form.adverts-form-aligned .adverts-field-name-adverts_eventUnits {
    clear: initial;
}

body .adverts-form .adverts-field-name-adverts_eventUnits > label {
    display: none;
}

body .adverts-form .adverts-field-name-adverts_eventUnits > #adverts_eventUnits {
    width: 112px;
}
```